# UTF-8 not supporting some characters

Tags: java, utf-8

My java application not supporting the Russian alphabets. Instead of letters, `????` is getting displayed. I am using UTF-8 encoding.

How can I resolve this Issue. I searched a lot but didn't get the solution.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use UTF-16/32?

Comment: It's getting displayed where? What kind of app is it? Where is the code reading and displaying the text?

Comment: @amit Here are a few reasons: http://utf8everywhere.org

Answer (score 2):

It is the **character set** which might or might not contain specific characters.

Unicode is such a character set which does contain the Russian alphabet (there are multiple versions of Unicode, but I believe all contain the full Russian alphabet).

UTF-8 is just an encoding, UTF-8 is just a standard how to convert Unicode codepoints into bytes. Using UTF-8 any Unicode codepoints can be represented with variable number of bytes.

Most likely the font you're using or your Operating System does not support displaying Russian characters, this is not an issue of UTF-8.

Try using other fonts (e.g. the default) and see if you still can't see the characters.